# Error al intentar hace un scaffold usando entity framework code first c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme los errores de la foto 
las clases son estas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

public class RobotDog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Armed { get; set; }
        public virtual RobotProduction RobotProduction { get; set; }

```
}

public class RobotFactory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RobotProduction> RobotProduction { get; set; }

}

public class RobotProduction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RobotdogId { get; set; }
    public int RobotFactoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }

    public virtual RobotDog Robotdog { get; set; }
    public virtual RobotFactory RobotFactory { get; set; }


}
public class RobotContext : DbContext
{
    public RobotContext() : base("RobotContext")

    { }
    public DbSet RobotDogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet RobotFactorys { get; set; }
    public DbSet RobotProductions {get;set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @Danny, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Hola, ¿tienes puesto el using System.Linq; al principio del código, en la declaración de usings? Porque ToList es, en efecto, un método de extensión

Comment: revisare @zeross

Comment: @S.Bonet si esta puesto

Answer (score 1):

Para poder utilizar los métodos `ToList`  y `Find` sobre un `DbSet`, tienes que establecer el tipo de entidad en tu `DbSet` de la forma `DbSet<NombreEntidad>`. tu clase `RobotContext` debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
public class RobotContext : DbContext
{
    public RobotContext() : base("RobotContext") 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<RobotDog> RobotDogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RobotFactory> RobotFactorys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RobotProduction> RobotProductions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();
    }
}
```